# Is it possible to get raw data from sony smartBand2?

Tags: sony, google-fit, wearables

I want the accelerometer data from Sony smartBand2. Is it possible to get that?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.sonymobile.com/2015/09/10/use-smartband-2-sensor-data-for-innovative-android-and-ios-applications/), you could use Google Fit API to store and access fitness data from any wearable and sensor.

Both [Google Fit Android APIs](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/) and [Google Fit REST API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/) work with three types of data: [Public data types](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#public_data_types), [Custom data types](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#custom_data_types), and [Shareable data types](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#shareable_data_types).

SmartBand 2 provides the following ***Public data types*** to the Google Fitness Store:

- google.step_count.delta (steps)
- google.heart_rate.bpm (heart rate in bpm)
- google.activity.segment (sleeping, walking, running)

You may also check this [tutorial](http://okinesio.org/development/how-to-get-raw-data-from-commercial-activity-trackers/#jt-sony-api) for additional information.